# ¿Cómo conocer el texto de un input y mostrarlo en un alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>celda 1</td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>3.000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div><input id="uno"> </input>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>2.000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("table tbody tr").change(function() {
      var total = $(this).find("uno").text();
      alert(total);
    });
  </script>
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Pero quiero mostrar en el `alert` lo que acabo de escribir en el `input` pero me dice indefinido. ¿Cómo puedo mostrar en el alert el texto que está en el `input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo es que no estabas accediendo al valor, por eso te decia indefeinido

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>celda 1</td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>3.000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div><input id="uno"> </input>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>2.000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("table tbody tr").change(function() {
      var total = $('#uno').val(); //esto linea fue todo lo que cambie
      alert(total);
    });
  </script>
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenías varios problemas:

1. `input` es una `etiqueta` que no tiene `etiqueta de cierre`
2. El valor de un `input` se captura con `.val()`
3. Dentro de tu `.find()` debes especificar que el elemento a buscar es un `id` colocando el `#`

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>celda 1</td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>3.000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div><input id="uno"></div>
        </td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>2.000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("table tbody tr").change(function() {
      var total = $(this).find("#uno").val();
      alert(total);
    });
  </script>
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: De todas formas, si ya conoces el ID, no necesitas hacer un find.

Comment: Si, pero si se coloca el `id` directo no podrá capturar el `input` perteneciente a cada `tr` en caso de haber más.

Comment: Aunque haya mas input no deberian tener el mismo ID! Si quieres capturar mas de uno lo ideal seria utilizar clases.

Comment: Es verdad al hacerlo dinámico debería cambiar `id` por `class`

Comment: O de lo contrario buscas por la etiqueta .find('input[type="text"]:first') asumiendo que el campo sea el primero

Answer (score 1):

Accede al input por ID `$("#id")` y luego guarda su valor `.val()` en una variable.

(Porque pides un alert del contenido del input, ¿verdad?)

```js
function alertar(){
  var mensaje=$("#alertado").val();
  alert(mensaje);
}

$("#alertado").change(alertar);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>celda 1</td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>3.000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Escribe" id="alertado" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>2.000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
      <div class="as-console">    
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada no se que es lo que deseas hacer realmente en el evento change de cada fila de la tabla. Tal ves el mejor evento seria el onClick o el MouseOver o algo parecido pero bueno, eso es a gusto del consumidor.

Lo que deseas realizar que es mostrar el texto almacenado en el input no te funciona porque estas llamando a una propiedad que no esta definida o sea no existe. Tendrias que **cambiar**:

```
//Esto
var total = $(this).find("uno").text();

//Por esto
var total = $(this).find("uno").val();
```

Ya que la el valor del campo se adquiere atraves de la función **val()** de JQuery, en caso que deseas asignarle un texto seria

```
campo.val('texto a aplicar');
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: "uno" es un ID, por lo que no vas a poder encontrarlo asi.

Comment: Eso lo se y se supone que va dentro del bloque que el mismo creo, es decir dentro de su vinculación al evento change. Lo puse asi para que escogiera en donde colocarlo. Por eso indique debes cambiar esto por esto.